# How can you output UPDATE / INSERT query results when using MySQL -e,--execute?

Tags: mysql, command-line

When using MySQL to run an UPDATE or INSERT, I get query result info:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

When using MySQL from the command line (eg: `mysql -e "UPDATE ..."`) I get no output for successful queries.

How can I get the query result info to output when using the --execute argument?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run with -vv, that will print the query being ran as well as the results you're looking for

Comment: #til there's -v -vv and -vvv (maybe more, but that's probably it), in the MySQL docs it describes it as -v -v -v

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the -vv output is useful when running sql from a file. e.g.

 ```mysql -uuzaname -p -hremote.com -vv < myfile.sql```